# How do I map double quotes in Vim

Tags: vim

```
println("Hello world!")
```

`ci(` can be used to modify the contents of parentheses in vim, There's an easier way: `cib`，Because `b` is an alias for parentheses. `ci"` can be used to modify the contents of double quotes, But double quotes don't have aliases, So I wanted to map one for it: `omap u \"`, But I found out that `ciu` doesn't work, How can I map u to double quotes? That is, I want to map one character to another. How do I do that?

```
println("Hello world!")
```

I hope that when I press `ciu`, it can have the same effect as pressing `ci"`, as follows:

```
println("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no `i` in `ci"`.**

There is:

- `c`, the `c` operator for "change",
- and `i"`, the "inner quotes" text object.

What you want is an "alias" for `i"`, not for `"`, which is done by mapping `iu` to `i"`:

```
onoremap iu i"
xnoremap iu i"
```

Note that `v`, `V`, and `<C-v>` are not operators so `onoremap` is not enough to cover all cases, a visual mode mapping is also necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much, the explanation was very clear and solved my problem perfectly!